# Set parameter of an object to it's default value in Django views

Tags: python, django

In my Django Models I have set default field to a field

For e.g.

```
Class Foo(models.Model):
    xyz = models.IntegerField(default=122)
```

Now when I am using it in some views, How can I set it to its default value after usage ?
I know I can do this:

```
a = Foo.objects.get(...)
a.xyz = 122
```

But is there a better method so that I don't have to re-write the default value in `Views`?

Answer (score 0):

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#default):

> The default value is used when new model instances are created and a value isn’t provided for the field. When the field is a primary key, the default is also used when the field is set to None.

So you cannot directly set the field of an existing instance to its default value. But you probably can find a trick :

```
FOO_XYZ_DEFAULT = 122

class Foo(models.Model):

    xyz = models.IntegerField(default=FOO_XYZ_DEFAULT)

# [...]

a = Foo.objects.get(...)
a.xyz = FOO_XYZ_DEFAULT
```

If the default value is a callable (lambda, function, etc) you also can reset the value to the rsult of this callable.